# Spring Boot doesn't consume command line argument with dot (.)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application which I can start with:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dserver_port=8080
```

But if I change the `underscore` to `dot`:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dserver.port=8080
```

The property: `server.port` will not consumed.

Does anyone know why?

**Update**
Samething happened if I do:

```
java -jar target/*.jar --server.port=8080  <-- doesn't consume
java -jar target/*.jar --server_port=8080  <-- works
```

Comment: The version with the dot works for me (windows).

Comment: @ESala thanks, yes.. it works for lots of the ppl.. that's my question, where can be wrong with this

Comment: Is it just the `server.port` property, or you see the same behavior with other properties? Also, are you doing something to the args of the main function before you call `SpringApplication.run(App.class, args)`?

Comment: @Esala all the properties, i have done nothing more than call the `run` method

Comment: How do you test if the property was consumed or not? Have you tried reading it from the environment with `env.getProperty("server.port")`, or `@Value` annotations or with a `@ConfigurationProperties` class?

Comment: @ESala check if the server starts with desired port..